# how to close navigation drawer from custom adapter class

Tags: java, android

I have implemented custom navigation drawer code in which I am replacing fragments in the main screen. It works, except the navigation drawer does not close automatically when selecting a row.

I dont know how to initialize the `mDrawerLayout` object the from the adapter class.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Please share some code

Answer (score 1):

```
/*closeDrawer() is used to close navigation drawer*/
    public void closeDrawer() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
```

Call closeDrawer() from your Adapter class